# what archetype that was used to generate a maven app?

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

Is there a simple way of finding out what archetype that was used to generate a maven app in the project. I dont't seem to find it in the pom.xml, but maybe Im looking in the wrong place? In my case it is  web app, but i don't know exactly what maven archetype that was used.

Answer (score 1):

No, that information is not provided in the generated Maven project.